# Layout drawing in XeLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

Could somebody help me, please, is it possible to make this layout drawing in XeLaTeX?

[image: Layout drawing]

Comment: It is, but it will require some work. Better do it in a program that is made to do this kind of work and include an image.

Comment: @Caramdir Ok. Thank you. So, my way is DraftSight. :)

Comment: Be sure to export to a vector format, for best results. [I see DraftSight supports PDF](http://184.106.235.187/q/what-file-formats-can-draftsight-export-to.html); try that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Καλησπέρα!

You could try to do them in tikz or pstricks. It shouldn't be too difficult, but I am not sure if it would be worth the effort especially if you don't know them or/and you are not going to need them in the future.

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/showcase/index.php?lang=en) is also an alternative, but (assuming that you are an engineer) a CAD program like the one you suggested would probably be the easiest solution for you - no need to learn something new.

If you need to add annotations at the drawings, in order to use the same fonts with the main text, you can try [adding them with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)

Comment: Thank you. :)))) Ευχαριστώ πολύ. I've tried to make this picture in DraftSight, but it's too difficult for me. So, as you advised I will use Inkscape. Thanks. :))

Comment: @filokalos You are welcome! In case you are going to need to do a lot of drawings in the future, consider becoming proficient with tikz. Ktikz is going to make it easier. In order to use ktikz with XeLaTeX you have to [change the default template](http://www.mechpedia.gr/wiki/Pgf/tikz#Ktikz) for the preamble.

Comment: Thanks. It's very good, it has also link for templates. I shell try to understand how it works. :) I'm not an engineer - it's for my work in Theologiki sxoli. :)